# Writing a function to split data in folders in Python (I wrote it but produces bad results)

Tags: python

I have a seemingly simple task to do:

1. I have 2 folders: cats and dogs. 1500 Corresponding images in both.
2. I want to copy 90% to cats/training and 10% to cats/testing and same for dogs.
3. I've written a function but somehow cats work but incorrectly while dogs don't work at all.

```
def split_data(SOURCE, TRAINING, TESTING, SPLIT_SIZE):
    source_files = [f for f in os.listdir(SOURCE) if os.path.getsize(os.path.join(SOURCE, f)) > 0]
    random.shuffle(source_files)
    
#here we've got the total number of files in cats/dogs parent folders
    total = len(source_files)
    
    to_training = source_files[0: int(total * split_size)]
    to_test = source_files[int(total * split_size):]
        
            
    for file_name in to_training:
        full_file_name = os.path.join(SOURCE, file_name)
    if os.path.isfile(full_file_name):
        shutil.copy(full_file_name, TRAINING)
    for file_name in to_test:
        full_file_name = os.path.join(SOURCE, file_name)
    if os.path.isfile(full_file_name):
        shutil.copy(full_file_name, TESTING)

#source directiories
CAT_SOURCE_DIR = "/tmp/PetImages/Cat/"
DOG_SOURCE_DIR = "/tmp/PetImages/Dog/"

#training directiories
TRAINING_CATS_DIR = "/tmp/cats-v-dogs/training/cats/"
TRAINING_DOGS_DIR = "/tmp/cats-v-dogs/training/dogs/"

#testing directiories
TESTING_DOGS_DIR = "/tmp/cats-v-dogs/testing/dogs/"
TESTING_CATS_DIR = "/tmp/cats-v-dogs/testing/cats/"

#let's test cats
split_size = .9
split_data(CAT_SOURCE_DIR, TRAINING_CATS_DIR, TESTING_CATS_DIR, split_size)

print(len(os.listdir('/tmp/cats-v-dogs/training/cats/')))
print(len(os.listdir('/tmp/cats-v-dogs/testing/cats/')))
#prints out 1486 and 1 (adding 1 to the testing each time i run it)

#checking dogs
split_data(DOG_SOURCE_DIR, TRAINING_DOGS_DIR, TESTING_DOGS_DIR, split_size)
print(len(os.listdir('/tmp/cats-v-dogs/training/dogs/')))
print(len(os.listdir('/tmp/cats-v-dogs/testing/dogs/')))
#prints 1 and 1, same story from the cats testing but in both folders this time
```

I'd appreciate any hint. Thank you in advance.

---

My EDITED code after reading one of the answers.

```
import sklearn
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def split_data(SOURCE, TRAINING, TESTING, SPLIT_SIZE):
    source_files = [f for f in os.listdir(SOURCE) if os.path.getsize(os.path.join(SOURCE, f)) > 0]
    random.shuffle(source_files)
    
    SOURCE_IMAGES = [os.path.join(SOURCE, i) for i in os.listdir(SOURCE)]
    SOURCE_IMAGES = random.shuffle(SOURCE_IMAGES)
    SPLIT_SIZE = 1 - SPLIT_SIZE

    to_training, to_test = train_test_split(source_files, test_size=SPLIT_SIZE)
    
    
    for i in to_training:
        if os.path.isfile(i):
            shutil.copy(to_training, TRAINING)
    for i in to_test:
        if os.path.isfile(i):
            shutil.copy(to_test, TESTING)
```

The problem is I still don't get all the files copied (just one item per running the cell). I need to be able to copy a whole batch of them. All of it must be done by defining one funtcion looking like this:

```
def split_data(SOURCE, TRAINING, TESTING, SPLIT_SIZE):
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this helps:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import os
import shutil

CAT_SOURCE_DIR = "/tmp/PetImages/Cat/"
DOG_SOURCE_DIR = "/tmp/PetImages/Dog/"

CAT_IMAGES = [os.path.join(CAT_SOURCE_DIR, i) for i in os.listdir(CAT_SOURCE_DIR)]
DOG_IMAGES = [os.path.join(DOG_SOURCE_DIR, i) for i in os.listdir(DOG_SOURCE_DIR)]

cat_train, cat_test = train_test_split(CAT_IMAGES, test_size=0.1)
dog_train, dog_test = train_test_split(DOG_IMAGES, test_size=0.1)

def copy(images, target_folder):
    for i in images:
        shutil.copy(i, target_folder)

#training directiories
TRAINING_CATS_DIR = "/tmp/cats-v-dogs/training/cats/"
copy(cat_train, TRAINING_CATS_DIR)
TRAINING_DOGS_DIR = "/tmp/cats-v-dogs/training/dogs/"
copy(dog_train, TRAINING_DOGS_DIR)

#testing directiories
TESTING_DOGS_DIR = "/tmp/cats-v-dogs/testing/dogs/"
copy(dog_test, TESTING_DOGS_DIR)
TESTING_CATS_DIR = "/tmp/cats-v-dogs/testing/cats/"
copy(cat_test, TESTING_CATS_DIR)
```

Comment: Thank you for this comment! I've tried to incorporate it to my code. I've edited the post to show how I did it. But my function still copies 1 file per running. The thing is I must define a function that takes such variables (SOURCE, TRAINING, TESTING, SPLIT_SIZE). The first three are just paths to directories. So I had to put in the code you showed me within my definition. I had to tweak it a bit as there was an error when passing 'i' as argument to shutil.copy.

Comment: Joanna, could you paste your error and whole code?